# A custom HorizontalScrollView,the method smoothScrollTo doesn't work

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have a custom HorizontalScrollView.But inside the class,the method smoothScrollTo doesn't work.The codes below is mine.

```
public class MyHorizontalScrollView extends HorizontalScrollView {
private int flagPosition;
private int scrollX;
private int windowWidth;

public MyHorizontalScrollView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    WindowManager manager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    DisplayMetrics outMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    manager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(outMetrics);
    windowWidth = outMetrics.widthPixels;

    flagPosition = windowWidth / 2;
}

public MyHorizontalScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    WindowManager manager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    DisplayMetrics outMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    manager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(outMetrics);
    windowWidth = outMetrics.widthPixels;

    flagPosition = windowWidth / 2;
}

public MyHorizontalScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    WindowManager manager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    DisplayMetrics outMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    manager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(outMetrics);
    windowWidth = outMetrics.widthPixels;

    flagPosition = windowWidth / 2;
}

@Override
public void setSmoothScrollingEnabled(boolean smoothScrollingEnabled) {
    super.setSmoothScrollingEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    int action = ev.getAction();
    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            scrollX = getScrollX();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            scroll();
            break;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
}

private void scroll() {
    if (scrollX <= flagPosition/2) {
        smoothScrollTo(0, 0);
    } else{
        smoothScrollTo(flagPosition, 0);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
    scrollX = getScrollX();
    Log.v("my", "myscroll======+++++++onscrollchange" + scrollX);
}
}
```

I want a result that,I scroll the HorizontalScrollView,when I scroll to a range,then uplift my finger,the HorizontalScrollView will scroll to a specific position automaticly.

This is my code.Inside the method scroll(),I toggle smoothScrollTo.It doesn't work.But the method scrollTo worked.I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

I put the codes inside the class:

```
    private Runnable run = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (scrollX <= flagPosition / 2) {
                MyHorizontalScrollView.this.smoothScrollTo(0, 0);
            } else {
                MyHorizontalScrollView.this.smoothScrollTo(flagPosition, 0);
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public boolean post(Runnable action) {
        return super.post(action);
    }
```

Then replace the method smoothScrollTo with post().And I realize the effect.